# Maximum likelihood estimation of parameter $N$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, multinomial-distribution

Every competitor in a marathon has a unique number on their shirt, from 1 to N. N is unknown. The observation is $n_1, \ldots ,n_K$, which are randomly sampled from the $N$ competitors with equal probability. What is the MLE for $N$?

My intuition is that the MLE is simply the maximum observed in that set but how do I prove this? At first I thought this was a multinomial but that doesn't make sense since there is a single observation or there would be K observations without replacement. Is this a categorical distribution? How do I derive the MLE for that?

Comment: This was supposedly something about how this question is beyond i.i.d. Thank you!

Comment: I am assuming $n_1,\ldots,n_K$ are i.i.d with common pmf $P(n_i=j)=1/N$ whenever $j\in \{1,\ldots,N\}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom : I'd have guessed it was without replacement, so not i.i.d. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Yes, this is without replacement (i.e each competitor has a unique number). With replacement, I'd get something like a multinomial. Does the discrete uniform distribution still hold then (à la German Tank Problem)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3277805/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that you get a particular subset of size $K$ from a population of size $N$ is
$$
\frac 1 {\binom N K} = \frac{(N-K)!K!}{N!}.
$$
This gets bigger as $N$ gets smaller. And $N$ can keep getting smaller until it reaches the maximum observed value; $N$ cannot be smaller than that.